# How to open another link after clicking the title in showing one page?

Tags: java, javascript, mysql, jsp, servlets

Before telling you question, I'll try my best to explain.

I've this website: http://technology-newstoday.rhcloud.com/

Here you could see that all news are listed in just one page, which looks pretty sh**t.

I'm fetching all news using MySql database and these are built in jsp and servlets.

***Question***
I want to show all that titles of news in just one page and after clicking that title, it should redirect to another page showing full news of that title. Hope so you understand what i'm trying to say.

I'm a student and don't have much experience about this. So please try to understand.

***Please help, what should i use here?***

***Surely, Help would be appreciated!!***

Comment: Use anchor tag. <a href="link to new page">title</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using pure java and jsp create a jsp or servlet that gets an `id` of a news and shows it. For example your jsp is `showSingleNews.jsp`. Send `id` of News to this jsp/servlet.

Your links will be something like these(the value of id is dynamic):

```
<a href="showSingleNews.jsp?id=1">Title of this news 1</a>
<a href="showSingleNews.jsp?id=2">Title of this news 2</a>
<a href="showSingleNews.jsp?id=3">Title of this news 3</a>
```

In your `showSingleNews.jsp` page get parameter's value and fetch it from database and show it:

```
<%
request.getParameter("id");
// And fetch this news from database and show it
%>
```

Comment: One more thing would like to ask... I want to retrieve that `id` from database .. Is it possible?

Comment: @mohanlal: You're welcome. Inform me if you have problem about it. Good luck :)

Comment: @mohanlal: You will fetch a news with that `id`. For example you can select a news by specified `id` with this SQL: `SELECT * FROM tblNews WHERE id=1`.

Comment: But i cannot list id=1, 2, 3..etc .. everytime... Any shortcut or tricks? Sir, i 'm student and want to explore more about this so pls sir..

Comment: @mohanlal: What do you mean by list id=1,2,3,... ? You fetch all id of news just in your first page that show all news title.

Comment: Okay man...thanks ..your answer was good... this is what i was looking for :) thanks again!!. Nice work.. contribute your answer with all in this community forum.